# How to allow access only from a specific host on Apache Httpd 2.4?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, apache2.4

I'm using `Apache Httpd 2.4` as a web server ,and I fail to allow access only from a specific host to a URL-path "/x" on my web server.

```
httpd.conf:

<Location "/x">
    Require host myhost.com
</Location>
```

Basically it ignores "Require host myhost.com" and restricts access from all hosts.

`authz_host`, `authz_core` modules are enabled.

Am I missing anything?

Thanks

Comment: This should work, I've just tested it. Do you maybe have some other configuration (e.g. `<Directory /var/www/x/>` overriding the Location directive?

Comment: @digijay I have also configuration for <Directory /var/www/html></Directory> just above the <Location "/x"></Location>

Answer (score 2):

To make `Require host` work, you have to make sure that reverse dns lookup for your domain works properly. This is done by `PTR` (pointer) records in your DNS. You can check it with the `dig` command like this:

```
$ dig +short www.google.de
172.217.22.67
$ dig +noall +answer -x 172.217.22.67
67.22.217.172.in-addr.arpa. 85372 IN    PTR fra15s17-in-f3.1e100.net.
67.22.217.172.in-addr.arpa. 85372 IN    PTR fra15s17-in-f67.1e100.net.
```

Note that the IP of the PTR record is reversed: 172.217.22.67 <=> 67.22.217.172

So www.google.com has a proper reverse dns entry.

If your domain has no reverse dns pointer set you will find an entry like this in your apache error log (unless you have configured it to be in a different location it should be `/var/log/apache2/error.log`):

```
[Wed Dec 05 16:18:23.854771 2018] [authz_core:error] [pid 4711] [client W.X.Y.Z:54050] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/example.com/x
```

As a workaround you could just use `Require ip`:

```
<Location "/x">
    Require ip W.X.Y.Z
</Location>
```

where W.X.Y.Z is your IP according to the entry in the error.log.

Hope this helps, if so I would be glad if you would accept the answer.

Comment: Hi Netanel, could you check again if you have any other directive affecting `Location /x`? This could be an alias or a Directory directive or something the like. Also, could you check if `Require ip` works?

Answer (score 0):

This is a real issue with no proper solutions on stackoverflow, so let me give the solution right here:

```
SetEnvIf Host ^myhost\.com$ valid_domain

<Location "/x">
    Require env valid_domain
</Location>
```

I don't know why this solves it, but it does